# Conversion issue from NSNumber to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsnumber

I'm parsing data from a JSON webservice and adding it to the database so when I insert an int, I have to convert it to NSNumber in this way it's working fine: 24521478

```
NSString *telephone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"telephone"]];
int telephoneInt = [telephone intValue];
NSNumber *telephoneNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:telephoneInt];

patient.telephone = telephoneNumber;
```

but when I want to display it and convert the NSNumber to NSString I'm getting wrong numbers: -30197

```
NSString *telephoneString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [user.telephone intValue], nil];
labelTelephone.text =telephoneString ;
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to represent a telephone number as an int. Also, I don't think it's a good idea to obtain an int from a `NSString` via method `intValue` which apparently is a telephone number.

Comment: I don't know why you gets that answer, but there's no need to convert the NSNumber to an int before you convert it to a string. You can just do, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.telephone]. If you log user.telephone, what do you get?

Comment: How does your telephone property look like?

Comment: A bit stronger than CouchDeveloper: Trying to represent a telephone number as an int is a rubbish idea. My phone number starts with "+44 (1" and is most definitely not a number. The "+" means "insert the digits to dial for phone calls to foreign countries, unless your country code is 44", so leaving that out messes up the number completely. "(1234)" means "the area code is 1234, so dial the digits that come before the area code followed by 1234, except if you dialed the country code, or if your area code is also 1234".

Comment: The reason for the problem is of course that "int" only holds values up to about +/- 2 billion, so 10 digit phone numbers starting with 3, 4, 5 etc. are guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Just adding that if the server guys are a bit more clever than the client guys, then the telephone number will arrive as a string in the first place, and that whole conversion palaver is nonsense.

Comment: ive tried with [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.telephone] but when i log t display -30197 but when i log in insert its 24521478 so the insert is good but there is a problem when i get it from the base

Comment: Is 24521478 the number you are actually using? There should be no trouble with converting an 8 digit string to an int then to an NSNumber, and finally to a string. So, are you saying that if you log user.telephone, it logs correctly as 24521478?

Comment: the problem is from the insert 

    NSString *telephone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"telephone"]];     
    int telephoneInt = [telephone intValue];
    NSNumber *telephoneNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:telephoneInt]; 
    
    NSLog(@"telephone :   %@",telephoneNumber);/// 24521487 
    
    patient.telephone = telephoneNumber;
    
    NSLog(@"telephone : %@",patient.telephone);////-30197 

why is this hapening  in my base telephone type is integer16

Comment: I am not sure but maybe 24521478 is out of range of the int data type..try using double instead..?long telephoneLong = [telephone longValue];

Comment: it's not solving th issue when iconvert it from nsstring to int to nsnumber and log it's  24521478 but after insert and log it's -30197

Answer (score 2):

NSNumber comes with dedicated methods for each data type.If you want to convert NSNumber to NSString use:

```
 NSString *telephoneString = [user.telephone  stringValue];
```

The issue may coming because of the data type you used for the variable patient.telephone

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the web service, then you should return the telephone number as string in the JSON

**Reasons**

1. if the telephone number begin with zero then the NSNumber will remove that zero as it has no value (**ex:** 00123456789 will be 123456789 which will wrong data)
2. You will not be able to display the telephone number is a user friendly way by adding "+" and "-"    (**ex:** +123-456-789)

You really should make the json return the number as string if you have a control over that

Comment: i have control but when i change it and change the coredata model i get The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store  how do i fix it

Comment: try to delete the app from the simulator to re-create the store